# Loewy structure of $S_4$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields, modules, modular-representation-theory

How to deduce the Loewy Structure of $kS_4$ where $k$ has characteristic 2. I can compute the Cartan matrix and Decomposition matrix with Brauer Characters without difficulties. But when it comes to determining the Loewy structure (other than the head and the bottom), I've been lead nowhere. I have two simple modules and two $8$-dimensional PIMs.

Comment: Please don't self-vandalize your question. You normally have a "delete" button under the line with tags. (The delete button is no longer available if there's a posted answer, but this is not the case.)

Comment: Simulposted to m.se, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3951011/loewy-structure-of-s-4 in violation of site norms.

Comment: I've deleted the other one.